# full outer join in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, outer-join

I have 2 tables A and B with columns, containing some details of students (all columns are integer):
A:
st_id,
st_subject_id,

B:
st_id,
st_subject_id,
st_count1,
st_count2

st_id means student id, st_subject_id is subject id.
For student id 15, there are following entries:
A:
15 | 1
15 | 2
15 | 3
B:
15 | 1 | 31 | 11
15 | 2 | 30 | 14
15 | 4 | 21 | 6
15 | 5 | 26 | 9
3 subjects in table A and 4 subjects(2 matching with table A and 2 extra) in table B.

I want to display the final result as:
15 | 1 | 31   | 11
15 | 2 | 30   | 14
15 | 3 | null | null
15 | 4 | 21   | 6
15 | 5 | 26   | 9

Can this be done using full outer join in SQL, or by another method?

Comment: Outer join would be fine - what's stopping you?

Comment: @Bashton While writing the full outer join, we need to give column names in select. But for some entries, I need to include st_id, st_subject_id from table A and sometimes from B. How should I pass these columns in the select statement? Can you please write a sample query. It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would suffice, but I can't test right now.
Coalesce means that the first non-null value will be selected from both tables.

```
select
coalesce(A.st_id, B.st_id) st_id,
coalesce(A.st_subject_id, B.st_subject_id) st_subject_id,
B.st_count1,
B.st_count2

from A

full outer join B
on A.st_id = B.st_id and A.st_subject_id = B.st_subject_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bashton!! Using coalesce totally solved my issue.

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped :)